# Difference btw. Graphics fillRect and clearRect

Tags: java, image, graphics, awt, bufferedimage

I noticed some interesting difference between fillRect and clearRect when I want to initialize a BufferedImage with a half-transparent background color:

using fillRect:

```java
Color someHalfTransparentColor = new Color(Integer.parseInt("77affe07", 16), true);
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(10, 10, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
g.setColor(someHalfTransparentColor);
g.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
g.dispose();
        
System.out.println(Integer.toString(bi.getRGB(0, 0), 16));
// WORKS NOT AS EXPECTED: 77b0ff06 != 77affe07
```

using clearRect:

```java
Color someHalfTransparentColor = new Color(Integer.parseInt("77affe07", 16), true);
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(10, 10, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
g.setBackground(someHalfTransparentColor);
g.clearRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
g.dispose();
        
System.out.println(Integer.toString(bi.getRGB(0, 0), 16));
// WORKS AS EXPECTED: 77affe07 == 77affe07
```

It seems when using fillRect the color values are slightly changed. Can someone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that `fillRect` uses the current composite ([`getComposite`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#getComposite())) of the `Graphics2D`, and `clearRect` ignores it. By default, the composite is [`AlphaComposite.SrcOver`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html#SrcOver). When drawing a new rect, this composite will decide the final color by combining the color at the destination and the color about to be drawn with some maths.

On the other hand, (at least on my version of the JDK) `clearRect` sets the composite temporarily to [`AlphaComposite.Src`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html#Src) (hence ignoring the current composite), which totally ignores the destination, and simply copies the color you want to draw to the place you want.

You can see that if you do `g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);` before `fillRect`, you get the same output as `clearRect`.

The parts of the docs that sort of mention this are:

[`clearRect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#clearRect(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)):

> This operation does not use the current paint mode.

[`setComposite`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setComposite(java.awt.Composite)):

> Sets the Composite for the Graphics2D context. The Composite is used in all drawing methods such as `drawImage`, `drawString`, `draw`, and `fill`. It specifies how new pixels are to be combined with the existing pixels on the graphics device during the rendering process.

It could be argued that:

- `clearRect` isn't a "drawing method". It erases things, so `setComposite` doesn't apply to it.
- the composite is part of the "paint mode" (the docs doesn't define this term for some reason), and so `clearRect` doesn't use it.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! So ist basically a rounding error when fillRect paints over the existing pixel colors and calculates the resulting color.

Comment: @jsteltze I'm not sure if it could be considered an "error" though. I haven't gone through how the maths work, but it could be the expected result of using the `SRC_OVER` rule with the destination pixel being a totally transparent pixel and the source pixel being your `someHalfTransparentColor`.